# Symfony FR3DLdapBundle configuration and service

Tags: php, symfony, fr3dldapbundle

I am writing a Test app in Symfony3 and I am trying to set up LDAP user authentication on top of my `FOSUserBundle` I have found this Symfony ldap Bundle: `FR3DLdapBundle` I followed the documentation and 'I think I set it up correctly'. Once I have done the configuration as specified [here](https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) when i refresh my page nothing happens no errors either. To check if anything has happened i used Wireshark to track if there was a LDAP call/pacage but nothing.

Security.yml:

```
security:
    erase_credentials: false

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            fr3d_ldap:  ~
            form_login:
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: /profile
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
                # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [fos_userbundle, fr3d_ldapbundle]

        fr3d_ldapbundle:
            id: fr3d_ldap.security.user.provider

        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

`congig.yml:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Test\TestBundle\Entity\User

# app/config/config.yml
fr3d_ldap:
      driver:
          host:                ldap.forumsys.com
  #       port:                389    # Optional
  #       username:            foo    # Optional
  #       password:            bar    # Optional
  #       bindRequiresDn:      true   # Optional
  #       baseDn:              ou=users, dc=host, dc=foo   # Optional
  #       accountFilterFormat: (&(uid=%s)) # Optional. sprintf format %s will be the username
  #       optReferrals:        false  # Optional
  #       useSsl:              true   # Enable SSL negotiation. Optional
  #       useStartTls:         true   # Enable TLS negotiation. Optional
  #       accountCanonicalForm: 3 # ACCTNAME_FORM_BACKSLASH this is only needed if your users have to login with something like HOST\User
  #       accountDomainName: HOST
  #       accountDomainNameShort: HOST # if you use the Backslash form set both to Hostname than the Username will be converted to HOST\User
      user:
          baseDn: ou=users, dc=host, dc=foo
          filter: (&(ObjectClass=Person))
  #       usernameAttribute: uid # Optional
          attributes:          # Specify ldap attributes mapping [ldap attribute, user object method]
  #           - { ldap_attr: uid,  user_method: setUsername } # Default
  #           - { ldap_attr: cn,   user_method: setName }     # Optional

  #           - { ldap_attr: ...,  user_method: ... }         # Optional
  #   service:
  #       user_hydrator: fr3d_ldap.user_hydrator.default # Overrides default user hydrator
  #       ldap_manager: fr3d_ldap.ldap_manager.default   # Overrides default ldap manager`
```

The documentation on this bundle is Poor yet it is suggested by everyone everywhere i google ldap Symfony.

**Question 1. How do I check or know that something is happening...?**

Lets assume that it works, I then created a service like this:

```
`        <!-- LDAP Connection -->
        <service id="test.testldap.ldap_adapter"
                 class="Test\TestBundle\CambioLDAP\LdapAdapter">
            <argument type="service" id="fr3d_ldap.driver"/>
        </service>`
```

Also added LdapAdapter:

```
<?php

namespace Test\TestBundle\CambioLDAP;

use FR3D\LdapBundle\Model\LdapUserInterface;

class LdapAdaptor
{
    private $ldap;

    public function __construct
    (
        LdapUserInterface $userInterface
    ) {
        $this->ldap = $userInterface;
    }
}
```

Not even sure if its the LdapUserInreface i should use it only gives me two options:

```
getDn
setDN
```

Either way Symfony gives me this error:

```
The service "test.testldap.ldap_adapter" has a dependency on a non-existent service "fr3d_ldap.driver".
```

Of course fr3d_ldap.driver is from config.yml.

**Question2 Which classes should I be extending**

Sorry for the length of this question but It seems Symfony2-3 is very poorly covered by LDAP as well as this bundle, wouldynt it be easier to use straight php to do this...?

Comment: Question2. What your service should do?

It doesn't have to extend anything if it isn't needed

Comment: You should use symfony LDAP Component. http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-ldap-component I've never got success with FR3DLdapBundle.

Comment: @AndrzejPiszczek I would like my service to give me connectivity to my Ad via LDAP, so then i can inject it and use what ever ldap las is reposnsible for connectivity and retriving data from my AD

Comment: @Mirouf well is this component compatable with Symfony3 if it is how do i use it once it is set up

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**:

List of loaded services you can check in console:

php app/console debug:container | grep YOUR_SERVICE_ID

Maybe your xml file with services isn't loading? Check in YourBundle\DependencyInjection\YourBundleExtension file which service file is loading.

Comment: Hey ye i know how to check the existing services, at the moment I cannot do that as i get error message. And my services.xlm is getting loaded as i have other services already in use.